# How to Identity the Inserted Records Order?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I have a table in sql server 2008, I need to identify the order of insertion in the table without using identity field. and also this table is not containing any datetime datatype field. pls suggest me the solution.

Comment: Do you have a primary key at all?

Comment: no, there is no key available in this table

Comment: Why do you have tables without keys?

Comment: @Aaron: it is a traditional system where this table has no references at all.

Comment: You don't need references between tables to make a primary key useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

There is *no* implied or built-in sort order to a table. A table is just a collection of rows. A query on the table has an an order (for example, earliest to latest) if you use an `ORDER BY something`.

You've said you have nothing like this. You have no options.

Answer (score 1):

A table, by definition, is an unordered set of rows. Think of throwing a bunch of bean bags on the floor. What order did they land in? Unless you've kept track while you were throwing them, or labeled them with 1,2,3 etc., you have no idea. (Let's ignore the case where they all happen to land on top of each other.)

You can't make any assumptions about order insertion (e.g. by using physical order or by believing the order that `SELECT *` with no `ORDER BY` returns) unless you have some other information to go by. Alex Kuznetsov has a [pretty short blog post demonstrating](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) that there are many variables that can shape order aside from order of insertion.